# Characterization of deterministic pushdown automata

Tags: automata-theory

Is there any known characterization for deterministic pushdown automata (DPDA)?
For example, visibly pushdown automata(VPA) is a subclass of DPDA, which is characterized by following syntactic condition: push or pop decision depends on the input symbol.
Similarly, is there any either syntactic or semantic condition, which when satisfied by a given non-deterministic PDA, guarantees its determinizability?

Comment: Deterministic push-down automata are already *defined* by a syntactic condition. So what is the question?

Comment: Well. Let me explain my question better. Let $A$ be given non-deterministic PDA. Does there exist an equivalent deterministic PDA? I think this question is undecidable in general. Is there any other condition (e.g input driven stack operations for VPA) known, which when satisfied by $A$ guarantees that $A$ can be made deterministic? Does undecidability of determinizability checking imply no such condition can ever exist?

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. You should include this explanation in the question itself (comments are not meant to be permanent).